# Metro Bundler error: Expected path […] to be relative to one of the project roots

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

When trying to run my React Native app I get this error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Expected path `/Users/jgallaso/Projects/aerogear/aerogear-react-native-core/index.js` to be relative to one of the project roots
    at toLocalPath (/Users/jgallaso/Projects/aerogear/aerogear-js-sdk/example/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/lib/toLocalPath.js:33:9)
    at ModuleCache.getModule (/Users/jgallaso/Projects/aerogear/aerogear-js-sdk/example/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/ModuleCache.js:94:20)
    at ModuleResolver._getFileResolvedModule (/Users/jgallaso/Projects/aerogear/aerogear-js-sdk/example/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:320:42)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/jgallaso/Projects/aerogear/aerogear-js-sdk/example/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:311:989)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/jgallaso/Projects/aerogear/aerogear-js-sdk/example/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:96:16)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/jgallaso/Projects/aerogear/aerogear-js-sdk/example/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:269:4352)
    at /Users/jgallaso/Projects/aerogear/aerogear-js-sdk/example/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:201:36
    at next (native)
    at step (/Users/jgallaso/Projects/aerogear/aerogear-js-sdk/example/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:256:306)
    at /Users/jgallaso/Projects/aerogear/aerogear-js-sdk/example/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:256:536
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░ 56.6% (331/440), failed.
```

My app has a dependency installed `aerogear-react-native-core` that is a Native Module. Source code is at: https://github.com/josemigallas/aerogear-react-native-core

This package on the other hand depends on other TS one (I ignore if this is problematic) and this code is located at: https://github.com/josemigallas/aerogear-js-sdk/tree/poc_react_native_library/packages/core

And the app code that actually tries to use all this is located at: https://github.com/josemigallas/aerogear-js-sdk/tree/poc_react_native_library/example/react-native

This means:

```
App
└─┬ aerogear-react-native-core@0.0.2
  └── @aerogearmobile/core@1.0.0
```

Since this is all at development stage, nothing is pushed to npmjs, I'm just using `npm link` to include all dependencies.

Honestly I don't have a clue why this is failing, without  the second dependency everything worked all right so that makes me think typescript has something to do. However, the error is complaining about `aerogear-react-native-sdk`'s index.js file so maybe the error is related with the link.

I tried deleting all caches, re-installing npm modules, re-running the bundler many times...

Answer (score 3):

If you have used "npm link" in the project, that might be the reason. Metro Bundler does not work with symlink correctly. Try to install the dependency without using "npm link".

Comment: One way  to install local packages is "install-local", which actually install the package without symlink. This worked for me when I encountered this issue.